# Flink + rocksdb taking a very long time to restore a large s3 checkpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

I am running a low-parallellism (4 slots) job whose checkpoints can get very large.
In the example I'm going to present the checkpoint was 142 GB, saved in S3 and it took 40 minutes to restore from there to a couple of EC2 instances with EBS volumes. I have exactly onces unaligned checkpoints enabled, and use rocksdb backend. I am using S3 presto library.

This is a flamegraph of the Task Manager after a couple of minutes:
[image: tm flamegraph start]
And this is after 20 minutes
[image: tm flamegraph after 20 min]

If I increase the number of slots from 4 to 12, it restores a bit faster: 25 min, but still prohibitive.

Apart from reducing the checkpoint size, is there anything else I can do to make it faster?
Are there metrics that I can enable that will allow me to identify the exact cause (e.g. slow internet connection, slowness due to EBS...)

Comment: Are you using incremental checkpointing?

Comment: Yes, I am using incremental checkpointing, and Flink 1.17

Comment: Do the checkpoint metrics show a lot of in-flight data being written into the checkpoints?

Comment: No. After restarting from scratch, the last 10 full checkpoint data size are reported to be from 38.9GB to 43.3GB, checkpointed data size from 9.9GB to 12.5GB in the last one, and he persisted in-flight data is 2MB at most, usually KBs.

Comment: Perhaps a [Task-Local Recovery](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/state/large_state_tuning/#task-local-recovery) mechanism + [link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/working_directory/#local-recovery-across-process-restarts) will help you